# How to stop `gcloud component update` from keeping a backup?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am building a google-cloud-sdk base-image and I am trying to keep it lean.

```
ARG GCLOUD_SDK_VERSION=285.0.1-alpine
FROM google/cloud-sdk:$GCLOUD_SDK_VERSION

# Install Java 8 for Datastore emulator
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        openjdk8-jre
RUN gcloud components install \
        cloud-datastore-emulator \
        pubsub-emulator \
        beta \
        --quiet
...
```

So far everything is fine. And when I build and look at the output of the `gcloud components install` command I feel confident:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│       These components will be installed.        │
├──────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┤
│           Name           │  Version   │   Size   │
├──────────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ Cloud Datastore Emulator │      2.1.0 │ 18.4 MiB │
│ Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator   │ 2019.09.27 │ 34.9 MiB │
│ gcloud Beta Commands     │ 2019.05.17 │  < 1 MiB │
└──────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

My final image size, however, is shocking: 1.11GB. When I look at docker history I see that the component installation actually contributed 654MB to the final image size:

```
CREATED BY                                      SIZE
/bin/sh -c gcloud components install        …   654MB
/bin/sh -c apk add --update --no-cache      …   78.2MB
```

I am currently assuming it has something to do with the final line of the installation process.

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Creating backup and activating new installation          ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

That appears to be a nice thing to have on your local workstation but not in a docker image. I tried to see if I can deactivate this backup or delete it afterward. There was no helpful paragraph in the man pages and searching online always directs me to some cloud database backup procedures you can initiate using `gcloud` commands.

Does anyone have further knowledge about what is happening here? Maybe it is not the backup at all that is contributing to most of the overhead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I want to thank @gso_gabriel for his suggestions. I ended up analyzing filesystem utilization before and after calling `gcloud components install`.

1. Getting rid of the backup turned out to be easy. In the gcloud application folder there is a hidden, hidden `.install/.backup` folder which was not there in the beginning and took up around 270 MB after component installation.
2. Installing components also left behind a bunch of `__pycache__` folders which summed up to around 100 MB.

To reduce the overall image size, I updated the corresponding docker line to:

```
RUN gcloud components install \
        cloud-datastore-emulator \
        pubsub-emulator \
        beta \
        --quiet \
    && rm -rf $(find google-cloud-sdk/ -regex ".*/__pycache__") \
    && rm -rf google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup
```

The improvement can be seen with `docker history`:

```
CREATED BY                                      SIZE
/bin/sh -c gcloud components install        …   317MB
```

A reduction of over 300 MB. I tested the image by using it as datastore and pubsub service for one of my applications, running its unit-tests. Everything still appears to be working well.

There might be more files that can be cleaned but I believe I got the heavy-weights already.

Comment: Thanks @Felix for providing the results from your investigation! Glad to hear that I could help you as well!

Comment: Alpine includes non-core components e.g. `rm -rf /google-cloud-sdk/bin/anthoscli` shaves off another 70MB

Comment: This is great, thanks. Though will those `__pycache__` files be required to regenerate at runtime, slowing down any use of them?

Comment: @Maximilian yes, maybe it will take a bit more time during startup. Good point. If a fast startup is critical then it might be best to leave them in there. Since I did not have that constraint for my use-case, I wanted the cleaner image.

Comment: @yan-hic But that file is built into the parent image so removing it in a later layer will have no effect on the image size.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels OP wants to build an image so yes, it does reduce the size of the container, which is then saved as image (docker save/commit)

Comment: @yan-hic Not in this case, as they're starting from a base image (google/cloud-sdk:$GCLOUD_SDK_VERSION) and the anthoscli file you're 'removing' originates in a previous layer from the layer in which you're removing it. So it's already commited to a layer and removing it later frees up no space. The only way to do that is to remove the file in the layer in which it was added, so in the same Dockerfile command. This means building the base image yourself too.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels Oh, I did not know that removing does not always equate to sizing down an image. Thanks for the insight. I have left my comment so reader understands the context of our replies.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you to run the command `gcloud components list`, to get a full list of components that are available and currently installed in your SDK - this way, you should be able to check which one is getting all this size on your installation.

Besides that, as mentioned in the documentation [Installing the Cloud SDK Docker image](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-docker):

> The Cloud SDK Docker Image is essentially Cloud SDK installed on top of a Debian-based OS image.

This means that probably part of the size is related to the OS of used for the installation.

I would like to also let you know that, it's not possible to not create the backup during the creation of the docker image.

For this reason, it might be worth it to contact Google directly, by raising a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), for this to be checked in the future - which would be good to have a better control over the components, such as the backup, for the image not be so big.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I called `gcloud components list` after the installation. It basically says the same thing as during installation. Only 18.4 MiB for Datastore emulator and 34.9 MiB for Pubsub emulator. Nothing else noteworthy.

I will investigate the other points you mentioned. and come back to this post.

Comment: Okay, while analyzing the installation before and after installing the components I found out that (a) the 700MB really originate from the gcloud installation folder and (b) There are some leftover `__pycache__` folders afterward. Removing the folders reduced the overall size of the image by 100MB.

Comment: I just found a `.install` folder on the root of the gcloud installation folder (`du -s ./*` does not show hidden files). This .install folder is hiding around 280 MB. And low and behold, there is a `.backup` folder in the `.install` folder with the bulk of those 280 MB. I need to test if I can just delete this folder and still run everything properly.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a late answer but what I ended up doing was modifying the google/cloud-sdk:alpine Dockerfile and added the code from the debian_component_based Dockerfile to install the components that I wanted as well as your fixes. This resulted in a docker image that only has the components that I needed while being smaller than the gcloud/cloud-sdk:alpine image.

Example:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add \
        curl \
        python3 \
        py3-crcmod \
        bash \
        libc6-compat \
        openssh-client \
        git \
        gnupg \
    && curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf google-cloud-sdk-${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    rm google-cloud-sdk-${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    /google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --bash-completion=false --path-update=true --usage-reporting=false \
    --additional-components alpha && rm -rf $(find google-cloud-sdk/ -regex ".*/__pycache__") \
    && rm -rf google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup
```

The resulting image size is 424 MB

Answer (score 1):

Let me add couple of additional things that we did in addition to what was already mentioned above. It shouldn't be used as an exhaustive answer, but can help you save couple of more megabytes (in our case more than 100).

You can also clean up the folder `google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis`.

What I figured out is that it's absolutely amust to keep
`secretmanager`, `iam`, `privateca`, `clouddeploy`, `binaryauthorization` folders and related files and file `apis_map.py` in that folder.

Everything else can be cleaned up if you do not need it. In our case we also kept some other apis that we need. So you still need to figure out what else do you need.

Hope that helps.